# Change BitmapSource Palette

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to change the palette of a BitmapSource in WPF? (at runtime)
Every BitmapSource hierarchy that I try has read-only access to palette.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to do it in a nice way, but you can always recreate a bitmap from the original one:

If you have:

```
Private myBitmap As System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap
Private myCurrentPalette As List(Of Color)
```

Then when you want to change your palette do this:

```
    Dim iWidth As Integer = myBitmap.Width
    Dim iHeight As Integer = myBitmap.Height
    Dim iPixel(iWidth * iHeight - 1) As Byte
    myBitmap.CopyPixels(iPixel, iWidth, 0)
    myBitmap = New WriteableBitmap(iWidth, iHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed8, New BitmapPalette(myCurrentPalette))
    myBitmap.WritePixels(New Int32Rect(0, 0, iWidth, iHeight), iPixel, iWidth, 0)
```

Then you need to apply:

`Image1.Source = myBitmap`

Comment: Why the `-1` on the height though, when making the array? Won't you lose a row of pixels that way?

Comment: The image is flatten to an array. So the LENGTH of the array is iWidth * iHeight, but the declaration of the array is going to be Dim iPixel(iWidth * iHeight - 1) As Byte.  (If my image a 2x2 image, I will have dim ipixel(3) as Byte.

Comment: Ah, right, that ugly VB weirdness of using the last index instead of the count... I'm more used to programming in c#